Structuring project folders with many datasets and models
I have a folder with different data, on which I'm training different models that I put in a single py file: models.py, as it's showed here:
my project
├───data
│   ├───data1.py
│   ├───data2.py
│   ├───data3.py
└───models.py
└───utils.py
└───etsimator.py

estimator is the method I'm testing to estimate some properties of these models. Hence, I need to train those models on each dataset to create a well-defined model for which I'm estimating its property.
However, to define a model, we need to go through the training process which requires access to the data file. For example, if we're considering training 2 models (logistic regression and decision tree) this will give a total of 6 models since we have 3 datasets.
Is there a better way (more compact) to organize my project?
EDIT
The data folder contains data preprocessing code, this is an example:
import numpy as np
def load_student_perf():
    X = np.load("data/raw/student_perf_X.npy")
    y = np.load("data/raw/student_perf_y.npy")
    return X, y
X, y = load_student_perf()


I'm not sure if there's an issue here (without knowing in detail what the data files contain).

Your project structure looks fine to me. However, I would personally like to organize the model scripts into separate files under the same directory. Here's how I would have organized this project:
my_project
├── data
│   ├── data1.csv
│   ├── data2.csv
│   ├── data3.csv
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── logistic_regression.py
│   ├── decision_tree.py
├── utils
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── data_loader.py
├── estimator.py

data_loader module abstracts loading data from the data folder for different datasets. Also each model now has a separate script under models directory.
So simply the estimator script would look like this:
from models import LogisticRegressionModel, DecisionTreeModel
from utils.data_loader import load_data

# Load data
data1 = load_data("data/data1.csv")
data2 = load_data("data/data2.csv")
data3 = load_data("data/data3.csv")

# Train models
logistic_model_1 = LogisticRegressionModel()
logistic_model_1.train(data1.drop("target", axis=1), data1["target"])

logistic_model_2 = LogisticRegressionModel()
logistic_model_2.train(data2.drop("target", axis=1), data2["target"])

# ... and so on for other models and datasets

# Rest of your code here
# ...


Thanks! Is it necessary then to create the folder models, if all the models are directly imported from the library Scikitlearn?

No it's not necessary.
